# Why MySQL chooses range scan (slow) vs index scan (faster)

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-performance, explain

I'm running into an issue where I have a table, described as follows:

```
mysql> desc myTable;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| score               | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| created_at          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| previous_score      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

With the following indexes:

```
mysql> show indexes from myTable;
+-------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                           | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| myTable |          0 | PRIMARY                          |            1 | id             | A         |          48 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myTable |          1 | index_my_table_on_previous_score |            1 | previous_score | A         |          48 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myTable |          1 | index_my_table_on_score          |            1 | score          | A         |          48 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

The issue is the following:

```
mysql> select count(*) from myTable where score > 10;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       48 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from myTable ignore index(index_my_table_on_score) where score > 10;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       48 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, using an index produces **slower** results than doing a **full table scan**. Since I have another index on the column `previous_score`, I decided to use `explain` to try and understand the issue further:

```
mysql> select count(*) from myTable where previous_score > 10;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       48 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, as you can see, nice and fast. Let's do the `explain` comparison:

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from myTable where score > 10;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | myTable | range | index_my_table_on_score | index_my_table_on_score | 5       | NULL |   24 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from myTable where previous_score > 10;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys                    | key                              | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | myTable | index | index_my_table_on_previous_score | index_my_table_on_previous_score | 4       | NULL |   48 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As additional information, the query I'm executing goes through all the results from my table (48).

- **Why, if the columns are defined exactly the same, and the indexes are exaclty the same, MySQL chooses to do a range scan for `score`, and a full index scan for `previous_score`?**
- **Secondly, why is a `range scan` slower than a `full index` scan? Range scan is supposed to be better than index scan, and index scan better than a full table scan. This is obviously not the case for my particular use case.**
- **Is there a way to suggest MySQL to do an index scan instead of a range scan?**

Any explanation or suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: 1- it depends on the data distribution,read about cardinality. Your 2 queries dont return the same number of rows 2- your sample is too small for meaningful comparisons,try it on millions of rows

Comment: Clear your query cache before re-running the same query. The difference was just to ignore the index, so I'm pretty sure that your full table scan simply pulled the data from cache which lead you to conclude that it's faster. Also, testing with such small amount of data and with response times below 10msec is just not a proper test, don't use such small numbers to pull off big conclusions.

Comment: Appreciate the comments, I'll take both into account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tiny tables like this, here is a way that is better than timing:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Summing up the column of numbers is a pretty good metric for comparing one variation of the `SELECT` to another.

Both of the `EXPLAINs` say they were `Using index` -- actually performing the query in the BTree that forms the index.  No table scan.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

If the 'cache' was cold, that could explain the `0.07 sec`.

Comment: Thanks for this tip to compare performance. the EXPLAIN does indeed show both queries are using the index (one scanning using range, another one using index scanning). I was wondering why MySQL would chose range over scan

Comment: Yeah, I don't know the subtle difference.